# Some of your hardware needs non-free firmware files to operate. The missing firmware files are: iwlwifi-2030-6. ucode iwlwifi-2030-5

Tags: debian, debian-installer, firmware, iwlwifi

Cant see WiFi Icon in Debian.
I'm using Dell Inspiron 15r 5520 i5.

This is the error I saw while installing.

`Some of your hardware needs non-free firmware files to operate. The firmware can be loaded from removable media, such as a USB stick or floppy.`

`The missing firmware files are: iwlwifi-2030-6. ucode iwlwifi-2030-5. ucode 
If you have such media available now, insert it, and continue.`

`Load missing firmware from removable media?`

[image]

Should I change the links?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your sources.list is correctly configured to install the non-free package `firmware-iwlwifi` which provide the `iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode` firmware. to install it:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install firmware-iwlwifi
```

Then run:

```
sudo modprobe -vr iwlwifi 
sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi
```

To apply the security updates you need to add `contrib non-free` to the security repository.

```
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free
```

Debian: [Example sources.list](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list)

Comment: Working great. Thank you so much